# Dummy audio output/pulse audio frozen on ubuntu?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 22.04, output, intel-atom

I have little to no knowledge of Ubuntu: after flashing the latest version of Ubuntu on my mini pc in dual boot, everything seems to be fine. After rebooting though, dummy audio output appears in the bar and pulseaudio remains stuck.

Worth mentioning that when I open pulseaudio, it remains stuck on "connecting to PulseAudio service". The output for systemctl - - user pulseaudio status is pulseaudio.service:Start request repeated too quickly and Failed with result 'signal'

Thank you very much

Tried the following:

- reinstalling pulseaudio and restarting it (E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed);
- attempted to replace pulseaudio with pipewire (the intel output is visible but no HDMI output when playing audio).
- systemctl --user enable pulseaudio followed by systemctl --user start pulseaudio (no output and no discernible effect on reboot)
- pulseaudio -D (no output and no discernible effect on reboot)

Comment: When mentioning "fixes" make sure you describe them and the results including error messages, etc. Also when dual-booting with Windows disabling its Fast Startup feature is a MUST. Have you done that? If not please do and shutdown, not reboot, so the setting sticks.

Comment: Thank you; I'll start by that.